# Apply multiple SparkML pipelines to a single DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I trained several ml pipelines with SparkML and persisted them in HDFS. Now, I want to apply the pipelines to the same dataframe. I implemented a generic scoring class which reads in the pipelines along with the data, applies each of the pipelines to the dataframe and appends the models predictions as new columns. This is my Java code example:

```
    List<PipelineModel> models = readPipelineModels(...)
    Dataset<Row> originalDf = spark.read().parquet(...)
    Dataset<Row> mergedDf = originalDf;
    for (PipelineModel pipelineModel : models) {
            Dataset<Row> applyDf = pipelineModel.transform(originalDf);
            applyDf = dropDuplicateColumns(applyDf, mergedDf); // drops columns in applyDf which are present in mergedDf
            mergedDf = mergedDf.withColumn("rowId", monotonically_increasing_id());
            applyDf = applyDf.withColumn("rowId", monotonically_increasing_id());
            mergedDf = mergedDf.join(applyDf, "rowId").drop("rowId").cache();
    }
```

I noticed some performance issues especially with large datasets. The join that is used to bind the dataframes is quiet expensive and a lot of shuffling is done between the stages.

Notice that I apply each model to the originalDf instead of mergedDf. If I apply the models to mergedDf in each iteration, I get an error saying that 'column xy is already present' from previous iterations.

Do you have any suggestions to improve the performance of this job?

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

- I wouldn't make two columns of `monotonically_increasing_id` separately. There's no guarantee that it will increment the same on both. Dataset 1 could get 1, 2, 3 and dataset 2 could get 1000, 2005, 3999
- I don't think you need to drop/merge DFs. I would just use the result of the applied model repeatedly.

Something like:

```
List<PipelineModel> models = readPipelineModels(...);
Dataset<Row> mergedDf = spark.read().parquet(...);
int i = 0;
for (PipelineModel pipelineModel : models) {
    i += 1;
    mergedDf = pipelineModel.transform(mergedDf);
    mergedDf = mergedDf.withColumnRenamed("yourModelOutput", "model_outputs_" + i);
}
```

FWIW I'm used to PySpark and kind of translating in my head - but that's the gist of how you'd solve it.